# Remoção de números aleatórios em árvore AVL

Tags: c, arquivo

Tenho que implementar uma avl que recebe 10 mil números aleatórios de 1 a 1000 000, logo após isso, tenho que remover 1 mil números aleatórios, ambos retirados de arquivos .txt, eu consigo inserir normalmente, mas na hora de remover,  ate consigo remover alguns, porem o cmd para de funcionar, gostaria da ajuda e vocês.

Abaixo o código para gerar os números

**[Atualização]**
rastreei e vi que o problema esta quando tenho que remover um número duplicado com 2 filhos. por exemplo. na arvore tem 2 numeros 500, e na função para remover pede para remover o 500, para remover um no com dois filhos tenho que pegar o menor no da arvore, pois é ai que acontece o loop infinito.

```
 #include 
 #include 
 #include
```

typedef struct no_arvore {
    int n;
    struct no_arvore *esq;
    struct no_arvore *dir;
} no_arvore;

//declaração devariaveis globais para contar as rotações duplas, simples e nos visitados na inserção
int Rdupla = 0;
int rSimples = 0;
int nVisitados = 0;
//fim da declaração.

int comparacoes = 0;

no_arvore *remover_no_arvore(no_arvore *r, int x);
int fator_balanceamento(no_arvore *r);
no_arvore *rotacao_simples_direita(no_arvore *r);
no_arvore *rotacao_simples_esquerda(no_arvore *r);

//Função que verifica se um nó está balanceado e faz as rotações necessárias.
no_arvore *verifica_balanceamento(no_arvore *r) {
    int fb;
    fb = fator_balanceamento(r);    //Após inserir o nó para esq ou dir, verificar Fator de bal.
    if (fb < -1) {
        if (fator_balanceamento(r->esq) > 0) {      //Rotação dupla a direita.
            Rdupla++; //conta rotações duplas.
            r->esq = rotacao_simples_esquerda(r->esq);
        }
        r = rotacao_simples_direita(r);             //Rotação simples a esquerda.
        rSimples++; //conta rotações simples.
    }
    else if (fb > 1) {
        if (fator_balanceamento(r->dir) < 0) {      //Rotação dupla a esquerda.
            Rdupla++; //conta rotações duplas.
            r->dir = rotacao_simples_direita(r->dir);
        }
        r = rotacao_simples_esquerda(r);            //Rotação simples a direita.
        rSimples ++; //conta rotações simples.
    }
    return r;
}

no_arvore *insere_arvore(no_arvore *r, int num) {
    if (r == NULL) {        //Se a árvore estiver vazia, inserir o nó.
        r = (no_arvore *)malloc(sizeof(no_arvore));     //Alocar o nó.
        r->n = num;                                     //Atribuir um valor para o nó.
        r->dir = NULL;                                  //Iniciar o filho direito.
        r->esq = NULL;                                  //Iniciar o filho esquerdo.
    }
    else {
        nVisitados ++; //soma o nos visitados.
                        //Se a árvore não estiver vazia, verificar se num é menor que n.
        if (num < r->n) {   //Se for menor, inserir a esquerda.
            r->esq = insere_arvore(r->esq, num);
        }
        else {              //Senão, inserir a direita.
            r->dir = insere_arvore(r->dir, num);
        }
        r = verifica_balanceamento(r);
        //Verificar balanceamento da árvore.
    }
    return r;
}

void busca_in_order(no_arvore *r, int num) {
    //Verificar se a árvore não está vazia.
    if (r != NULL) {
        if(r -> n != num){
            comparacoes++;
            //Se a árvore não estiver vazia, executar a busca.
        busca_in_order(r->esq, num);        //1 - Buscar na árvore esquerda.
        //printf("%d ",r->n);           //2 - Mostrar a raiz.
        busca_in_order(r->dir, num);        //3 - Buscar na árvore direita.

```
    }else{
        //printf("%d ", r -> n);

        }
}
//Se a árvore estiver vazia, não executar a busca.
```

}

void busca_pre_order(no_arvore *r) {
    //Verificar se a árvore não está vazia.
    if (r != NULL) {
        //Se a árvore não estiver vazia, executar a busca.
        printf("%d ",r->n);         //1 - Mostrar a raiz.
        busca_pre_order(r->esq);    //2 - Buscar na árvore esquerda.
        busca_pre_order(r->dir);    //3 - Buscar na árvore direita.
    }
    //Se a árvore estiver vazia, não executar a busca.
}

void busca_pos_order(no_arvore *r) {
    //Verificar se a árvore não está vazia.
    if (r != NULL) {
        //Se a árvore não estiver vazia, executar a busca.
        busca_pos_order(r->esq);    //1 - Buscar na árvore esquerda.
        busca_pos_order(r->dir);    //2 - Buscar na árvore direita.
        printf("%d ",r->n);         //3 - Mostrar a raiz.
    }
    //Se a árvore estiver vazia, não executar a busca.
}

int altura_arvore(no_arvore *r) {
    if (r== NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int altEsq, altDir;
        altEsq = altura_arvore(r->esq);
        altDir = altura_arvore(r->dir);
        if (altEsq > altDir) {
            return altEsq + 1;
        }
        else {
            return altDir + 1;
        }
    }
}

int fator_balanceamento(no_arvore *r) {
    //Fator de Balanceamento = Altura da sub-arvore direita - Altura da sub-arvore esquerda.
    return altura_arvore(r->dir) - altura_arvore(r->esq);
}

no_arvore *rotacao_simples_direita(no_arvore *r) {
    no_arvore *q = r->esq;
    r->esq = q->dir;
    q->dir = r;
    return q;
}

no_arvore *rotacao_simples_esquerda(no_arvore *r) {
    no_arvore *q = r->dir;
    r->dir = q->esq;
    q->esq = r;
    return q;
}

//Funçães que retorna o endereço do menor nó da árvore.
no_arvore *menor_no_arvore(no_arvore *r) {
    no_arvore *aux = r;
    while (aux->esq != NULL) {  //Procurar o nó mais a esquerda (menor nó da árvore).
        //printf("aux: %d\n", aux->n);
        aux = aux->esq;
    }
    //printf("aux: %d\n", aux->n);
    return aux;                 //Retornar o endereço do menor nó da árvore.
}

//Função que remove um nó que é folha (não possui filhos).
no_arvore *remover_folha(no_arvore *r) {
    printf("\nA folha %d foi removida com sucesso!\n", r->n);
    //getch();
    free(r);
    return NULL;
}

no_arvore *remover_1filho_esquerda(no_arvore *r) {
    no_arvore *aux = r->esq;
    printf("\n numero %d foi removido com sucesso!\n", r->n);
    free(r);
    return aux;
}

no_arvore *remover_1filho_direita(no_arvore *r) {
    no_arvore *aux = r->dir;
    printf("\n numero %d foi removido com sucesso!\n", r->n);
    free(r);
    return aux;
}

no_arvore *remover_2filhos(no_arvore *r) {
    no_arvore *aux;
    int x;
    aux = menor_no_arvore(r->dir);  //auxiliar recebe o endereço do menor nó da árvore.
    //printf("aux: %d\n", aux->n);
    x = aux->n;                     //guardar o valor do auxiliar em uma variável x.
    r = remover_no_arvore(r,x);     //remover da árvore o nó que substituirá o nó com 2 filhos.

```
r->n = x;                       //substituir o valor do nó com 2 filhos.
return r;
```

}

//Função para verificar o tipo de nó que será removido.
no_arvore *remover_no(no_arvore *r) {
    //Verificar se o nó é uma folha (Não possui filhos).
    if (r->dir == NULL && r->esq == NULL) {
        //printf("O no %d eh uma folha.\n", r->n);
        r = remover_folha(r);
    }
    else {
        if (r->dir == NULL) {
            //printf("O no %d possui 1 filho para esquerda.\n", r->n);
            r = remover_1filho_esquerda(r);
        }
        else {
            if (r->esq == NULL) {
                //printf("O no %d possui 1 filho para direita.\n", r->n);
                r = remover_1filho_direita(r);
            }
            else {
                //printf("O no %d possui 2 filhos.\n", r->n);
                r = remover_2filhos(r);
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}

no_arvore *remover_no_arvore(no_arvore *r, int x) {
    //Verificar se a árvore não está vazia.
    if (r != NULL) {
        //Se a árvore não está vazia, buscar o elemento x.
        if (r->n == x) {    //1 - Verificar se o elemento x está na raiz.
            //printf("ENCONTREI!: %d\n", r->n);
            r = remover_no(r);  //Chamar a função para remover o nó.
        }
        else {
            //Se x não está na raiz, verificar para qual lado x está.
            if (x < r->n) {
                //Fazer chamada recursiva para a esquerda.
                r->esq = remover_no_arvore(r->esq, x);
            }
            else {
                //Fazer chamada recursiva para a direita.
                r->dir = remover_no_arvore(r->dir, x);
            }
            r = verifica_balanceamento(r);
            //Verificar balanceamento da árvore.
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Elemento nao encontrado: %d\n", x);
    }
    return r;
}

no_arvore *inserir_aleatorio(no_arvore *r){
    int num;

```
char url[]="aleatorios.txt";
FILE *Ale;
Ale = fopen(url, "r");
if(Ale == NULL){
    printf("Error ");
}else{
    while(fscanf(Ale, "%d\n", &num)!=EOF){
        r = insere_arvore(r, num);
    }
}
fclose(Ale);

return r;
```

}

void busca_aleatorio_1000(no_arvore *r){
int num;

```
char url[]="aleatorios1000.txt";
FILE *Ale;
Ale = fopen(url, "r");
if(Ale == NULL){
    printf("Error ");
}else{
    while(fscanf(Ale, "%d\n", &num)!=EOF){

        busca_in_order(r, num);
    }
}
fclose(Ale);
```

}

no_arvore *remover_no_arvore_aleatorio(no_arvore *r) {

```
int num;

char url[]="aleatorios1000Remocao.txt";
FILE *Ale;
Ale = fopen(url, "r");
if(Ale == NULL){
    printf("Error ");
}else{
    while(fscanf(Ale, "%d\n", &num)!=EOF){

        r = remover_no_arvore(r, num);

    }
}
fclose(Ale);
    return r;
```

}

int main() {

```
no_arvore *raiz = NULL;

raiz = inserir_aleatorio(raiz);
printf("\nrotacoes simples: %d",rSimples - Rdupla);
printf("\nrotacoes duplas: %d", Rdupla);
printf("\nvisitas: %d\n\n",nVisitados);

remover_no_arvore_aleatorio(raiz);

system("pause");
```

}
 inserção

```
     # include < stdio.h>
     # include < stdlib.h>
     # include < time.h>
```

`int main(){
int i;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("aleatorios.txt", "w");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("erro.\n");
    return 1;
}
srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
for(i=1; i<10000; i++){
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", 1 + rand()% 1000000);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;`

}

`#include <  stdio.h>
#include <  stdlib.h>
#include <  time.h>

int main(){
int i;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("aleatorios1000Remocao.txt", "w");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("erro.\n");
    return 1;
}
srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
for(i=1; i<1000; i++){
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", 1 + rand()% 1000000);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
<code>`

Comment: Na função de remover "filho" você dá free e depois atribui NULL? Acredito que seja necessário uma atribuição, já que só é possível saber se está no fim da árvore quando os dois filhos são NULL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu problema está na remoção com dois filhos.

```
no_arvore *remover_2filhos(no_arvore *r) {
    no_arvore *aux;
    int x;
    aux = menor_no_arvore(r->dir);  //auxiliar recebe o endereço do menor nó da árvore.
    //printf("aux: %d\n", aux->n);
    x = aux->n;                     //guardar o valor do auxiliar em uma variável x.
    r = remover_no_arvore(r,x);     //remover da árvore o nó que substituirá o nó com 2 filhos.

r->n = x;                       //substituir o valor do nó com 2 filhos.
return r;


}
```

Veja o que o seu código está fazendo:

[image: Estado inicial da função]

[image: Elemento encontrado em menor_no_arvore(r->dir)]

[image: valor recebido por x]

Repare que tudo aconteceu como deveria, entretado nesta linha você está chamando a função de remoção novamente:

```
r = remover_no_arvore(r,x);
```

Agora, a mesma árvore da primeira imagem é recebida, ele verifica que a raíz contém o elemento desejado para remoção, identifica que possui dois filhos, busca o menor no filho da direita, encontra 500, chama a função de remoção para o número 500, identifica que é o elemento da raiz, identifica que possui dois filhos, busca o menor filho da direita, encontra 500, chama a função de remoção para o número 500, identifica que é o elemento da raiz, identifica que possui dois filhos, busca o menor filho da direita, encontra 500, chama remoção para o número 500... ... ... ... ...

O problema é que você está identificando corretamente a existência de dois filhos, entretanto você deseja remover o menor filho da direita e a função destacada acima passa o valor do menor filho da direita a ser removido e a mesma raíz ou subárvore é passada para esta função.

Ao invés de:

```
r = remover_no_arvore(r,x);
```

Tente:

```
r = remover_no_arvore(r->dir,x);
```

Assim você garante que você deseja remover o elemento x que se encontra na direita da árvore, ao invés de passar a própria árvore para remover o elemento x.

O problema que você está tendo é uma recursão infinita, como cada chamada de função cria uma pilha para que o programa saiba voltar de onde ele veio, a criação de pilhas sem fim gerará o problema que, em inglês, chama-se StackOverflow (estouro de pilha).

Se isso estiver correto, você veio ao site StackOverflow buscar uma solução para StackOverflow :D

Tente corrigir isto e veja se funcionou.

Comment: Obrigado Murillo, eu não tinha percebido isso(talvez tinha sido o sono), esta funcionando perfeitamente agora, adicionei outras linha de código, porque as vezes a função remover_no_arvore, retornava nullo e dava problema em atribuir o x. enfim, funcionando perfeitamente,